# Вывести повторяющиеся слова

Tags: c#

Есть строка с набором слов, которая вводится с клавиатуры, потом записывается в строковый массив. Необходимо вывести повторяющиеся слова.

Answer (score 1):

Найти повторяющиеся слова можно, например, так:

```
var repeatedWords = 
        from word in line.Split(' ')
        group word by word into same
        where same.Count() > 1
        select same.First();
```